# Text Mining error

Tags: text-mining, orange

I'm trying to get used to text mining using orange. I set up a very easy workflow loading a corpus (tab separated text file containing 10 entries), using a corpus viewer that shows my data correctly and a topic discovery item. But I always receive an error Message at 95% of topic discovery called:

```
Message: "Error calling '%s' of '%s'"
Arguments: ('set_data', 'Topic Discovery')
```

What do you think am I doing wrong here?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Stefan

Comment: The title of this post is very vague. Can you be specific about what kind of error you're having? Maybe mention you're using Orange?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed about Orange is that anytime you get an error calling `set_data`, there will be some sort of `ValueError` or `FormatError` that it is a child of.

Take a look at the rest of the errors and look for some type of value or formatting error, or post your full error log in a pastebin so I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you running? Does the same happen on the 0.2.2 version released a few days ago (note that for 0.2.2 you need also the newest version of Orange; i.e 3.3.9)?

It looks like you're not doing anything wrong but rather that this is a bug. If you could paste the whole error log, perhaps also a schema and a sample of the data if possible, along with the version of Orange and Orange3-Text that you are running I promise to take a look and fix the bug.